# match record you do not know exists

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table that has several columns and I need to find a way to see how many rows in that column match because I need every matched item to have the same value and then go to the next value.

```
mysql> select name,Location from relays
    -> ;
+----------+----------+
| name     | Location |
+----------+----------+
| Relay 1  | 3        |
| Relay 2  | 3        |
| Relay 3  | 3        |
| Relay 4  | 3        |
| Relay 5  | 3        |
| Relay 6  | 4        |
| Relay 7  | 6        |
| Relay 8  | 7        |
| Relay 9  | 9        |
| Relay 10 | 8        |
+----------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I know that I can do a select query and use the where part of a select and just ask for the number 3 but I want to be able to do that without having to put it in the code.

Here is what I have now so I can see it work so I have print statements in it.

```
a = 1
cursor.execute("SELECT Location FROM relays")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print row[0]

   if (row[0] == '3'):
      print "temp"+str(a)
   else:
      a = a+1
      print "temp"+str(a)
```

It prints out exactly what I need but I do not want to put the number 3 in the if statement.

Here is what I get..

```
3  temp1
3  temp1
3  temp1
3  temp1
3  temp1
4  temp2
6  temp3
7  temp4
9  temp5
8  temp6
```

I am building a config file on the fly and I will use this exactly as it prints out but will be put in a function I am creating.

If I add relay 11 and put it in Location 6 then I would like it to print out this..

```
3  temp1
3  temp1
3  temp1
3  temp1
3  temp1
4  temp2
6  temp3
7  temp4
9  temp5
8  temp6
6  temp3
```

I have tried using the counter a in the place of the 3 but it does not get the correct answer it just makes all the temp values increased by 1.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. I see you keeping the counter when there is a 3, otherwise increasing it, but then decrementing it on the second occurrence of a 6?

Comment: Do you just want to know how many unique Locations there are? So, there are five `3`s, one `4` etc. or are you trying to find out where are the "holes" in your Locations?

Comment: I am trying to find how many unique Locations. I have used this..  Select Location, count(*) from relays GROUP by Location and I get this.. 3,5 4,1 etc but do not know how to use these results. row[0] is Location and row[1] is the count but now trying to make my code create the last thing I have above.

Comment: so if Location 3 is in the tables 5 times I want my script to print temp1 5 times then move to Location 4 and print temp2 1 time and then go to Location 6 and print temp3 1 time but if I add another location 6 then it must print temp3 2 times. I hope this is clear for you cricket_007

Comment: there is no order in a database table. so unless you use an ORDER BY clause the results are not in a guaranteed order. you don't really explain your question clearly. and you don't explain the need for the GROUP BY clause. perhaps you could explain with a different, or perhaps actual example what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Here is what works but I have to add the while loop for every Location
'code'  b = 0
a = 1
cursor.execute("SELECT Location, count(*) FROM relays GROUP by Location")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:

   while (b < row[1]):
     print "temp"+str(a)
     b = b+1
  
b=0
while (b < row[1]):
     a = a+1
     print "temp"+str(a)
     b = b+1
'code'

Comment: Here is what works but I have to add the while loop for every Location
`code`  b = 0
a = 1
cursor.execute("SELECT Location, count(*) FROM relays GROUP by Location")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:

   while (b < row[1]):
     print "temp"+str(a)
     b = b+1
  
b=0
while (b < row[1]):
     a = a+1
     print "temp"+str(a)
     b = b+1
`code`